# Mostrar graficamente una cola con listas enlazadas

Tags: java, lista, queue

estoy haciendo un programa que utilice una cola implementando listas enlazadas, pero no tengo claro como puedo mostrar los elementos de la cola haciendo el dibujo de la cola  como se muestra en la imagen adjunta

[image: Representación gráfica de la cola]

Se deben dibujar los rectángulos y flechas con el contenido de la cola dentro de ellos, en este caso los números ya que la cola solo puede recibir números enteros y para hacer el dibujo puede utilizarse cualquier librería que permita dibujar

Esta es la porción de código que tengo hecho, ya la cola permite ingresar y eliminar números por lo que no hay problema en ese aspecto:

```
class Node
{
    private int data;
    private Node next;
    
    public Node(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
    }
    
    public int getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
    
    public void setData(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }
    
    public void setNext(Node next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }
           
}

class MyQueue 
{
    private Node rear;
    private Node front;
    private int size;
    
    public boolean isEmpty() 
    {
        boolean response = false;
        if (size == 0)
        {
            response = true;
        }
        return response;
    }
    
    public void enQueue(int element)
    {
        Node node = new Node(element);
        if(front == null)
        {
            rear = node;
            front = node;
            size++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha ingresado el numero "+element);
        }
        else
        {
            rear.setNext(node);
            rear = node;
            size++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha ingresado el numero "+element);
        }
    }
    
    public MyQueue() //Constructor 
    {
        front = null;
        rear = null;
        size = 0;
    }
    
    public Node deQueue()
    {
        Node response = null;
        if(front != null)
        {
            if(front.getNext()!= null) //Si solo existe un elemento en cola
            {
                int eliminado = front.getData();
                response = new Node(front.getData());
                front = front.getNext();
                size --;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha eliminado el numero "+eliminado);
            }else //Si existe mas de un elemento en cola
            {
                int eliminado = front.getData();
                response = new Node (front.getData());
                front = null;
                rear = null;
                size--;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha eliminado el numero "+eliminado);
            }
        } else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cola se encuentra vacia");
        }
        return response;
    }
    
    public Node peek()
    {
        Node response = null;
        if(!isEmpty())
        {
            response = new Node(front.getData());
        }
        return response;
    }
    
    public int getSize() //Obtiene el numero de elementos en la cola
    {
        return size;
    }
    
    public void verificarVacio() //Comprueba si la cola esta vacia y responde si o no
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Si ");
        }
        else 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No ");
        }
    }
    
    public void vaciar() //Vacia la cola
    {
        front = null;
        rear = null;
        size = 0;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha vaciado la cola ");
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuál es tu duda específicamente? Qué librería usar para graficar en Java?

Comment: La librería sé que puede ser graphics, mi duda es como crear el método de display para que los elementos de la cola aparezcan dentro de los rectángulos dibujados

Comment: Te recomiendo entonces que edites tu pregunta y especifiques cuál es tu problema en cuanto al uso de dicha librería. Si no expones un problema puntual podrían cerrar tu pregunta por ser poco clara